# How to make contacts list interactive?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So I am following this tutorial https://medium.com/@XensS/flutter-v-material-design-ii-7b0196e7b42d  and I am trying to make some like a contacts list where you click on the contact, and it takes you to another screen with all there person information. But I am just getting stuck, I am not sure how to add the interactivity so when you click on an contact, it will take you to there personal page. This is my code so far. 
Code to display list of contacts and search bar :

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
class ContactsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  Widget appBarTitle = new Text("Contacts");
  Icon actionIcon = new Icon(Icons.search);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new _ContactPage();
  }
}

class _ContactPage extends State<ContactsPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: widget.appBarTitle,
            actions: <Widget>[
              new IconButton(
                icon: widget.actionIcon,
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if (widget.actionIcon.icon == Icons.search) {
                      widget.actionIcon = new Icon(Icons.close);
                      widget.appBarTitle = new TextField(
                        style: new TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                            prefixIcon:
                            new Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.white),
                            hintText: "Search...",
                            hintStyle: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          print(value);
                          //filter your contact list based on value
                        },
                      );
                    } else {
                      widget.actionIcon =
                      new Icon(Icons.search); //reset to initial state
                      widget.appBarTitle = new Text("Contacts");
                    }
                  });
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
          body: new ContactList(kContacts)),

    );
  }
}

class ContactPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Contacts"),
        ),
        body: new ContactList(kContacts));
  }
}


class ContactList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Contact> _contacts;

  ContactList(this._contacts);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new ListView.builder(
      padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return new _ContactListItem(_contacts[index]);
      },
      itemCount: _contacts.length,
    );
  }
}

class _ContactListItem extends ListTile {
  _ContactListItem(Contact contact)
      : super(
      title: new Text(contact.fullName),
      leading: new CircleAvatar(child: new Text(contact.fullName[0])));
}
```

And this is the code which stores all contact information:

```
class Contact {
  final String fullName;

  const Contact({this.fullName});
}


const kContacts = const <Contact>[
  const Contact(
      fullName: 'Joey Trib',

  ),
  const Contact(
      fullName: 'Johnny Boy',

  )
];
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to that is in the repository for the tutorial you reference

```
List<_ContactListItem> _buildContactList() {
return _contacts.map((contact) =>
                      new _ContactListItem(
                        contact: contact,
                        onTap: () { _showContactPage(context, contact); }
                      ))
                .toList();
}

void _showContactPage(BuildContext context, Contact contact) {
Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute<Null>(
  settings: const RouteSettings(name: ContactPage.routeName),
  builder: (BuildContext context) => new ContactPage(contact)
));
}

}
```

Source:

https://github.com/fabiomsr/Flutter-StepByStep/blob/master/step5/lib/module/contacts/contact_list_view.dart#L110

Comment: @ dazza5000 So how would I work this into code that I have, without it throwing errors? Im new at this.